# AutoCompleteTextView with Parse.com (Android)

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I'm new to Android in general, so I looked up the documentation for `AutoCompleteTextView`.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, USERS);
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
        findViewById(R.id.searchUserTextField);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I see that it's up and running with very little code.

```
private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
        "user1", "user1", "user3", "user4", "user5"
};
```

I realize this is a stretch, but what would the next steps be with respect to implementing an autocomplete function based on my ParseUser table, especially as the text in the `AutoCompleteTextView` is changed by one character at a time?. Obviously, I wouldn't populate the USERS array with a Parse query displaying all of my users on each attempted search. How would I logically arrange such a thing?

To begin with, I'd probably include a `TextChangedListener`:

```
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (count % 3 == 1) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textview.setDropDownHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        adapter.clear();
                        // Run my background task here


                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    textView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterview, View v,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            searchUserTextField.setText(adapterview.getItemAtPosition(position)
                    .toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

But what would I provide as the background task? What am I querying so that I'm not searching through, say, 1000 users all at once, which is how many users I have in my app currently?

Comment: What is your use case? For example do you want any user to search for any user? Or just from those they have previously searched/connected with? And where is the ParseUser table stored?

Comment: By ParseUser table I meant querying the standard User class in Parse. I would say that they should be able to search for any user, so typing the letter "s" will bring up the first 100 users that start with s (I think Parse limits the query to 100 by default); typing "sa" would narrow the search criteria, and so on and on toward "sally", for example.

Comment: Maybe only run the query if the text hasn't changed for a little while, maybe something like half a second.  So when the text changes, set a timestamp and post to a handler with a delay.  After the delay, if the timestamp hasn't changed run the query.  Just off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work. It's static in the sense that it always prints out the first 100 users in your User class. I'm sure you could add a constraint that matches the first or second letters of the AutoCompleteTextView to the usernames.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    public void done(List<ParseUser> parseUsers, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("users", "Retrieved " + parseUsers.size());
            ParseUser[] data = parseUsers.toArray(new ParseUser[parseUsers.size()]);
            String[] strings = new String[data.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                strings[i] = data[i].getString(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME);
            }
            // Test to see if it was correctly printing out the array I wanted.
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, strings);
            AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchUserTextField);
            if(parseUsers.size() < 40) textView.setThreshold(1);
            else textView.setThreshold(2);
            textView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Log.d("users", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```